# sevenzipjbinding: How do I properly close file handles as they become unneeded?

Tags: java, 7zip

We have an application that uses sevenzipjbinding to bundle and transport content. 99% of the time, everything goes smoothly, however there are some edge cases where these zip files contain upwards of a hundred thousand files. When this happens, the number of file handles that the process has a hold on gets too high and then things start to fail.

I haven't been able to find a recommended way to handle this issue. Currently, we create a `RandomAccessFileInStream` upon request using an instance of `IOutCreateCallback`, but these never get closed until the very end. There is no apparent method in the interface designed to signify when a stream should be closed.

Currently, my only idea is to keep track of the "last" file that was requested and then every time a new one is requested to close the last file. If I do this though, I'm worried that I risk that 7zip wants to read the file a second time.

Is this a bug in my code, or is it in sevenzipjbinding?

Current implementation:

```
public ISequentialInStream getStream(int i) throws SevenZipException {
    ISequentialInStream is = null;
    try {
        AbstractItem item = getItem(i);
        
        if (item instanceof FileItem) {
            is = new RandomAccessFileInStream(((FileItem) item).getRandomAccessFile());
        } else if (item instanceof StreamItem) {
            is = new InputStreamSequentialInStream(((StreamItem) item).getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SevenZipException("IO Error!", e);
    } finally {
        closeables.add(is);
    }
    
    return is;
}
```

Comment: I think it is a bug in your code, but I can not spot it. As far as I have seen it, code like yours is difficult to debug, because it does not split the technical from the problem. Could you refactor your code, so that everythink about zip is in one try-with-resource-block and the rest of your code just produces byte[] or something like this?

Comment: Wouldn't this just change the problem from a file handle issue to a memory issue? Reading 100k+ files into memory and storing them as byte arrays is still a problem because the streams aren't closed?